# Mark correct checkbox and UPDATE correct row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, function

I can not find correct way how to Update correct row in mysqli from checked checkbox. If I submit button it update all fields. if I use ifset outside while loop it make changes only with first row. Can you please suggest something?

```php
function display_orders(){

          $query = query("SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY order_id DESC");
          confirm($query);

        while($row = fetch_array($query)) {

          $order_id = $row['order_id'];
          $order_amount = $row['order_amount'];
          $order_transaction = $row['order_transaction'];
          $order_status = $row['order_status'];
          $order_currency = $row['order_currency'];
          $order_date = $row['order_date'];
          $order_date = strtotime($order_date);
          $order_date = date('d-m-Y', $order_date);

          $checked = $row['mark_as_done'];

// 

    check if is mark as done or empty
        if($checked === "done"){

         echo $checked_status = "checked";

        }else{
          echo $checked_status = "";
        }

if isset submit updates the table

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

          global $connection;

          $value = $_POST['done'];
          $update_query = "UPDATE orders SET mark_as_done=? WHERE order_id =?;";

          $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);

          if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $update_query)){

            echo "SQL failed";
          }
          else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $value, $order_id);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
          }
        }
//read information from database

        $orders = <<<DELIMETER

        <tr>
            <td><a href="index.php?order_details&id={$order_id}">{$order_id}</a></td>
            <td>{$order_transaction}</td>
            <td>{$order_amount}</td>
            <td>{$order_currency}</td>
            <td>{$order_status}</td>
            <td>{$order_date}</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="index.php?delete_order_id={$order_id}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
            <td>
form to get information about checked fields

              <form class="" action="index.php?orders" method="post">
              <input type="checkbox" name="done" value="done" {$checked_status}>
              <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

              </form>
            </td>

        </tr>

        DELIMETER;
        echo $orders;
           }
}
```

Looks like simple task but cant find out.

Comment: If it matters, I will observe that `DELIMETER` isn't a word.

Comment: Please use correct indentation so your code is actually readable

Comment: The FORM for each row that is generated should have an ID that relates to the record so that the UPDATE will work with the correct record. As it stands now that does not appear to be the case

Comment: `action="index.php?orders"` < for one, suggests an GET array which I don't see any reference to anywhere, as well as the function you're using for all this.

Comment: `value="done" {$checked_status}` < that doesn't do anything.

Comment: value="done" {$checked_status} this in front page marks if it is checked or not - reading from database.

Comment: I have to think how to get correct id out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a tad confusing / convoluted but perhaps this might be more inline with what you are trying ( I think ) to accomplish. The generated forms need some way to refer to the record which they are to update - in this case the `order_id` would appear to be the correct choice. To that end a hidden field with the order_id value will be submitted with the form ( still unclear what `done` is supposed to do other than supply a value of `"done"` )

```
function display_orders(){
        $query = query( "SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY order_id DESC");
        confirm($query);

        while($row = fetch_array($query)) {

            $order_id = $row['order_id'];
            $order_amount = $row['order_amount'];
            $order_transaction = $row['order_transaction'];
            $order_status = $row['order_status'];
            $order_currency = $row['order_currency'];
            $order_date = $row['order_date'];
            $order_date = strtotime($order_date);
            $order_date = date('d-m-Y', $order_date);

            $checked = $row['mark_as_done'];


            if( $checked === "done" ){
                $checked_status = "checked";
            }else{
                $checked_status = "";
            }

        $orders = <<<DELIMITER
        <tr>
            <td><a href="index.php?order_details&id={$order_id}">{$order_id}</a></td>
            <td>{$order_transaction}</td>
            <td>{$order_amount}</td>
            <td>{$order_currency}</td>
            <td>{$order_status}</td>
            <td>{$order_date}</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="index.php?delete_order_id={$order_id}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
            <td>

              <form action='index.php?orders' method='post'>
                  <input type='checkbox' name='done' value='done' {$checked_status} />
                  <input type='hidden' name='order_id' value='{$order_id}' />
                  <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
              </form>
            </td>
        </tr>

        DELIMITER;
        echo $orders;
    }




    if( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['order_id'], $_POST['done'] ) ){

        global $connection;

        $id = $_POST['order_id'];
        $value = $_POST['done'];

        $update_query = "UPDATE orders SET mark_as_done=? WHERE order_id =?;";

        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);

        if( !mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $update_query)){
            echo "SQL failed";
        } else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, "ss", $value, $id );
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hai #RamRaider Tanks for your help. Now it is working. You gave me new ideas how can use hidden input fields.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, perhaps consider accepting the answer if it helped